# Does my app contain encryption with this video line of code- IOS- Xcode 6

Tags: ios, video, encryption

Does my app contain encryption with a video file? This is the code I have:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle]     pathForResource:@"Video1" ofType:@"mp4"]];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *PlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:PlayerController];
PlayerController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
[PlayerController.moviePlayer play];
PlayerController = nil;
```

Does my app contain encryption with the above code?

Comment: Why would you think encryption might be involved in any way with the posted code?

Comment: I thought of it because of NSURL in it. Is that only when It has a https?

Comment: Your URL is simply a reference to a file packaged with your app.

Comment: Okay so I don't have to worry about saying yes to encryption for this code?